Matrix splitting method for solving singular linear system
I'm studying the paper "OSQP: an operator splitting solver for quadratic programs" from Bartolomeo Stellato, et al. In section 4 solution polishing, the author solves a linear system Kt = g which is understood as the KKT system of equality constrained QP. $K$ looks like
$$
K = \begin{bmatrix}
Q & A^T \\
A & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $Q$ is positive semidefinite and it is assumed that the KKT system has a solution.
In case K is singular, e.g., when the active constraints are degenerate, the author adds a small perturbation $\delta>0$ and $K$ becomes
$$
\tilde{K} = K + \Delta K= \begin{bmatrix}
Q + \delta I & A^T \\
A & -\delta I
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The author then solves the new system through what I understand as matrix splitting method
$$
(K + \Delta K)t^{k+1} = \Delta K t^k + g
$$
However, the above system converges globally if the iteration matrix $(K+\Delta K)^{-1}\Delta K$ has largest eigenvalue smaller than 1, which is not the case as we can have the largest eigenvalue equals to 1.
Did I miss anything, or the method is only a local convergence when $t^0$ is close to a solution, for example, a minimum norm one?

@Balajisb, sorry for the confusion. Q is positive semidefinite so that the original QP is convex.I will modify the question.
